# R - d3heatmap color palette, 2-sided

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap using the `d3heatmap` package with the colors

```
red for the values below -2
yellow between -2 and -1.65
green between -1.65 and 1.65
yellow again between 1.65 and 2
red above 2
```

I have used the search and found only solutions with a palette 1-sided palette. I am not sure whether this is the problem, but using:

```
d3heatmap(mydata, 
    dendrogram = "none",
    colors = c("red", "yellow", "green", "yellow", "red"),
    breaks = c(seq(-10, -2), seq(-2, -1.65), seq(-1.65, 1.65), seq(1.65, 2), seq(2, 10)), 
)
```

(There are no values above 10)

Unfortunately, this yields funny results where I do not fully understand the colors in the heatmap, e.g. yellow for 0.125 or green for 1.69.
I also tried varying the length of the `colors`-sequences and `colorRampPalette` with similar results.

Comment: your `break` vector has 24 points, so the 5 colors are pbly recycled, try `breaks=c(-2,-1.65,1.65,2)`

Comment: Just tried - not working.